# getting most liked posts by users using act as votable gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7, acts-as-votable

I want to display the top 10 users whose posts got the most likes in past 2 hours, how can I do that
inquest index to get user

```
<%@users.each do |user| %>
  <%if user.id != current_user %>
  <%=user.email%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

inquest.controller index

```
def index
@users =  User
```

.joins(inquests: :votes)
.where('inquests.updated_at > ?', (Time.current - 2.hours))
.order('inquests.cached_weighted_average desc')
.limit(10)
@inquests = Inquest.all.order(created_at: :desc)
@inquest = Inquest.new
end

inquest model

```
class Inquest < ApplicationRecord
acts_as_votable
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, -> {order(:created_at => :desc)}, dependent: :destroy
has_many_attached :images 
validates :description, presence: true

validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { 
    :maximum => 250,
    :tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) },
    :too_long  => "Please limit your summary to %{count} words"
  }
end
```

here is scheema.rb file

```
  create_table "inquests", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title", null: false
t.text "description"
t.integer "creator_id"
t.integer "cached_votes_total", default: 0
t.integer "cached_votes_score", default: 0
t.integer "cached_votes_up", default: 0
t.integer "cached_votes_down", default: 0
t.integer "cached_weighted_score", default: 0
t.integer "cached_weighted_total", default: 0
t.float "cached_weighted_average", default: 0.0
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "cached_scoped_subscribe_votes_total", default: 0
t.integer "cached_scoped_subscribe_votes_score", default: 0
t.integer "cached_scoped_subscribe_votes_up", default: 0
t.integer "cached_scoped_subscribe_votes_down", default: 0
t.integer "cached_weighted_subscribe_score", default: 0
t.integer "cached_weighted_subscribe_total", default: 0
t.float "cached_weighted_subscribe_average", default: 0.0
t.index ["creator_id"], name: "index_inquests_on_creator_id"
end
  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "votable_type"
t.integer "votable_id"
t.string "voter_type"
t.integer "voter_id"
t.boolean "vote_flag"
t.string "vote_scope"
t.integer "vote_weight"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: 
"index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
t.index ["votable_type", "votable_id"], name: 
 "index_votes_on_votable"
t.index ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: 
"index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"
t.index ["voter_type", "voter_id"], name: 
"index_votes_on_voter"
 end
```

this is giving the error Can't join 'Inquest' to association named 'votes'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add this to your inquests table https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching

Add below association in inquest model.

`has_many :votes, as: :votable`
and run below query

```
User
   .joins(inquests: :votes)
   .where('inquests.updated_at > ?', (Time.current - 2.hours))
   .order('inquests.cached_weighted_average desc')
   .limit(10)
```

OR

```
User
  .joins('INNER JOIN inquests ON inquests.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN votes ON votes.votable_id = inquests.id')
  .where('inquests.updated_at > ?', (Time.current - 2.hours))
  .order('inquests.cached_weighted_average desc')
  .limit(10)
```

Comment: Can't join 'Inquest' to association named 'votes'; perhaps you misspelled it? 
I'm getting this error , 
I did it in controller index action like this

Comment: Can you please check in schema.rb file. What is the name for votes table?

Comment: `User has_many inquests` . right?

Comment: "votes" is the table name , and yes user has many inquests

Comment: i updated my scheema file , in question as well it gives the same error , where I missed something ?

Comment: I have updated my answer . Please follow it